# Why did Membership.GetUser().Email return the wrong value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have an MVC web application where a form is posted by ajax to a controller method that starts out like this:

```
[HandleError]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[Authorize]
public JsonResult FormSubmitMethod (FormCollection formCol) {
    MembershipUser myObject = Membership.GetUser();
    Guid currentUserID = (Guid)myObject.ProviderUserKey; // correct guid
    string emailAddress = myObject.Email;  // incorrect email returned one time
        ...and so on
```

I use the Guid ProviderUserKey to look up data about the user and perform all of my regular updates etc.  The email address returned from myObject.Email is used as the recipient address in a confirmation email sent at the successful conclusion of all regular transaction processing in the controller method.

I understand that perhaps I should instead be doing:

```
MembershipUser myObject = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
```

And maybe that is my problem.

This code has been running in production for a couple of years with no reported problems and thousands of successful email confirmations sent.  There are no recent changes to the code.

This week I had someone report they received an email from this controller method when it was intended for someone else.  I am trying to sleuth out how this happened.  Other facts and things that I know about what happened:

1. The correct user name is in the IIS logs as expected, including on this specific POST request.
2. The correct user data was updated everywhere I expect it in my database.  So I conclude that the ProviderUserKey is correct even in this unusual case.
3. The email address that was returned from Membership.GetUser().Email is a valid email address for another user of my site.  They have not logged in at all any time recently -- it has been months since they last logged in.
4. The two users in question have nothing to do with each other.  It wasn't a case where they were forwarding emails or causing the problem on their side.
5. The user who was logged in and should have received the email was a brand new user.  They had just newly registered their account about 10 minutes before the above controller method was invoked.  They successfully posted some other forms (not via ajax however) a few minutes prior to this controller.  Actually the other forms they posted were old-school webforms formviews.
6. I am using plain old forms authentication with the SQL Server provider.
7. It feels like a red herring, but both users happen to share the same first name, and it is a somewhat unusual spelling of that first name.  Their last names and everything else are different.

Is it plausible or expected for Membership.GetUser().Email to return a seemingly random user's email address rather than that of the current logged in user?  If so why?

Comment: `Membership.GetUser()` with or without userName does the same thing. If you do not provide the user name explicitly it tries to fetch using the current `HttpContext` or `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`. 

The method `Membership.GetUser()` will throw an exception if it can not find a non-empty user name value. So its fail safe for a broken request context.